# Why doesn't the unavailability of a file give negative value to $v0?

Tags: assembly, file-io, bitmap, mips

```
#only 24-bits 600x50 pixels BMP files are supported
.eqv BMP_FILE_SIZE 90122
.eqv BYTES_PER_ROW 1800

.data
#space for the 600x50px 24-bits bmp image
.align 4
res:    .space 2
image:  .space BMP_FILE_SIZE

fname:  .asciiz "source1.bmp"

.text
#====================================================
# main - main program
#----------------------------------------------------
main:
    ## read bitmap file into 'image'
    jal read_bmp

exit:   
    li  $v0,10      #Terminate the program
    syscall
#=====================================================

read_bmp:
    #push $ra to the stack
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     
    sw  $ra, 4($sp)
    #push $s1  to the stack
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     
    sw  $s1, 4($sp)

    # open file for reading
    li $v0, 13
        la $a0, fname   #file name 
        li $a1, 0       #0 - open for reading
        li $a2, 0       #0 - ignore length ($a2 = the length of bytes to read)
        syscall
    move $s1, $v0       # save the file descriptor

    lw $s1, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $s1
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra
```

Firstly, there is no file named ***`source1.bmp`*** in the directory. So, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56094932/159072),

> [image]

this program should load a negative value into **`$v0`**.

But, my output is as follows:

[image]

What is going on here?

**How can/should I do the error check then?**

Comment: At what location are you looking at `$v0`? Also what simulator are you using? It works fine for me in `xspim` (returns `-1`). Double check that the file indeed does not exist :) PS: `move $s1, $v0` is pointless if you are restoring `$s1` from stack immediately afterwards.

Comment: @Jester, after `syscall` before `move`.

Comment: To be sure change file name to something that definitely does not exist, `nosuchfile.txt` or similar :)

Comment: @Jester, can u tell me how a 600X50 24-bit bitmap sizes to 90122 bytes? 24-bit bitmap's header size is 54 byte. So, where does the rest of the bytes come from?

Comment: `600*50*3` plus the size of the bmp header (which should be 124 not 122 though)

Comment: @Jester, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Example_1 according to this 24-bit bitmap has 54 bytes of header.

Comment: Actually it has a 14 byte BMP header and a 108 byte DIB header (version `BITMAPV4HEADER`) so 122 it is.

Comment: @Jester, I don't see it. Coz, I am supposed to use 24-bit bitmap.

Comment: See example 2 on that page, that has a `BITMAPV4HEADER`.

Comment: @Jester Most BMP files use the "old" header format which is only 40 bytes (14+40=54) in length.

Comment: @MartinRosenau that may be but the question is specifically about one that doesn't: _"how a 600X50 24-bit bitmap sizes to 90122 bytes"_